# Repeat dynamically subreport on main NET rdcl Report, a time for each row

Tags: .net, rdlc, dynamically-generated, subreport

I need to configure a subreport that has a specific structure, to be repeated for each row of my dataset on a RDCL report dynamically. I saw that I can add the subreport item to a table, but I can't see a way to send the parameters to the subreport.

Does anyone know a way to do this?